# Sharing controller and views between projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create a good infrastructure for my web framework I am developing I have the following structure so far

solitude.admin web project to keep the controlers and views in how do I create this one I created a class libary but see you cannot have a web.config there

solitude.core will contain all my utililties and models

solitude.framework will be the core and meat of the cms platform my quesiton is how does one create a class libary project for asp.net mvc 4.6 to allow controllers and views to be shared i addded razor to a dll but i dont think that is correct approach

solitude.mvc this will contain the front end of the site  i tried the below changing project guids to allow the sharing but its not working
[image]

I also changed the project type guids as suggested on aricltes on so but no joy I am trying to mimic our other platforms already work to futher my understanding.

```
 <ProjectGuid>{152C761A-DD2E-4C1F-AF89-DFB2547A3BCA}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>solitude.admin</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>solitude.admin</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Another point is if I was two have two sep projects admin and web how would one tell it to go to admin if user types www.domain.com/admin but yet be two independent web projects?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see good the separation of concerns. But have some questions:

1.- Why not making "solitude.admin" another web app project?

2.- Why aren't you using the expected [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)? That is a lot of lowercases you got there.

3.- Why would you like/need to share Controllers? Basically, there must be a

```
return View();
```

inside them.

For views, you could create some components based on parameters (which mostly, it comes to print out some HTML). You already have [Shared Views](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/06/19/asp-net-mvc-tip-5-create-shared-views) but for the same project.

Comment: please do not create a answer when you are manly commenting if you do not have enough points please ignore question. I am trying to mimic nop commerce they way they sep their two sites front end and admin

Answer (score 0):

I totally understand you. I'm in the same situation. I suggest you take a look at AREAS. I'm still learning it, but for what I've googled, it is the proper way to share views and controllers between projects. 
This is one good [link](http://arunendapally.com/post/how-to-use-a-mvc-area-in-multiple-applications)